# search the text which is present in database or in template files

Tags: database, magento-1, product-list, list.phtml, template-hints

I want to change text in site.

when i tried template path hints, it did't worked for me.

the text is present in list view page, i tried in list .phtml, no luck.

i searched in static blocks and cms pages, still no luck

is there any way we can search the text which is present in database.

if you visit [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cases-covers/xperia-z.html?tp=1&code=magento) & search for "folks" you can  find text in italics, i want to chnage that text to normal font using phtml code.

Comment: First of all find id="ias_noneleft_1465888770785" in your list page if id exists then check there is any text

Comment: @HarryP there is no id as `ias_noneleft_1465888770785` in list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your any one file have jquery as below this code come from jquery find it and replace it

```
window.SgyIAS = {
        debug: false,
        _log: function(object) {
            if(this.debug) {
                console.log(object);
            }
        },
        init: function(){
            jQuery.getScript("http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/js/jquery/infinitescroll/jquery-ias.min.js", function() {
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        var config = {
                            item: '.products-grid',
                            container : '.category-products',
                            next: '.next',
                            pagination: '.toolbar .pager',
                            delay: 600,
                            negativeMargin: 2500,
                            history: {
                                prev: '.prev'
                            },
                            noneleft: {
                                text: '<em>That\'s All Folks! </em>',
                                html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align: center;">{text}</div>'
                            },
```